# How to write a magic-image class object as png file using code?

Tags: r

How can a svg read in with `magick::image_read_svg()` be written as a png file using code (not point and click)?

Example:

```
library(magick)
obj <- image_read_svg("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gilbarbara/logos/master/logos/r-lang.svg")
class(obj)
[1] magick-image
```

[image]

#### What I tried

I thought it would be simple, along the lines of

```
obj
png("myfile.png")
```

But no file is written

Answer (score 0):

Although the resulting object is `magick-image` class, it contains a regular bitmap array, and so can be treated as such

```
obj <- image_read_svg("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gilbarbara/logos/master/logos/r-lang.svg")
obj[[1]]
4 channel 256x193 bitmap array: 'bitmap' raw [1:4, 1:256, 1:193] 00 00 00 00 ...
```

Once you know how to access the bitmap array, it's as simple as

```
library(png)
png::writePNG(obj[[1]], "myfile.png")

dir()
[1] myfile.png
```